# When function on multiple columns using regex

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to apply a when function on multiple (hundrets) columns.
I want to check if at least one of the columns contains a specific value.

Is there a better way than doing this?

```
df.withColumn("any value", F.when(
   (col("check1") == "value") |
   (col("check2") == "value") |
   (col("check3") == "value") |
   (col("check4") == "value") |
   ...
   , True)
```

Is it possible to do that with a regex?

Comment: where is the regex in your code?

Comment: The regex is not the issue. I just need to know if it's possible to check multiple columns for True.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f.lit(True).isin(*columns)` to detect any true value:

```py
boolean_columns = [f.col(name) for name, _type in df.dtypes if _type == 'boolean']
df = df.withColumn('any true', f.lit(True).isin(*boolean_columns))
```

Comment: You asked for regex, but I'm giving another solution that looks more simple

Comment: Well, I want wo avoid writing all the columns. That's why the regex solution. :-)

Comment: Is the type of all these columns boolean? If you could post your .printSchema() output would help.

Comment: @Dusty I updated my answer considering to search for `True` in all columns of boolean type

Comment: Should the isin function not be used the other way? You are using the list comprehention similar to a udf. I think the code would crash.

Comment: I updated my question, to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your `value` is in the array of all columns. Please note that the list comprehension I'm using is **not** similar to UDF. It's a completely normal standard PySpark operation.

```py
# sample data
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  A|  B|  C|  D|
# |  B|  C|  D|  A|
# |  B|  C|  D|  E|
# +---+---+---+---+

df.withColumn('random', F.lit('A').isin([F.col(c) for c in df.columns])).show()
# +---+---+---+---+------+
# |  a|  b|  c|  d|random|
# +---+---+---+---+------+
# |  A|  B|  C|  D|  true|
# |  B|  C|  D|  A|  true|
# |  B|  C|  D|  E| false|
# +---+---+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! If this is all PySpark, I suppose this is just as fast as manually writing all the columns to check.

Comment: If I would like to do a >0 comparison on any row, how would that be possible?